# Can characters see themselves if invisible?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, vision-and-light, invisibility

Extraneous background info: The heroes are in a chamber full of mirrors with no doors, transported there by a nefarious wizard. The entire room is colored monochrome in black and white, except the heroes who remain in full color.

But the characters are all under the effect of the spell Invisibility. Can each character see their own body? I'm trying to determine if they are aware of the unusual coloring scheme.

Comment: "I'm trying to determine if they are aware of the unusual coloring scheme." As opposed to thinking they've gone color blind?

Comment: To answer your question yes. My phrasing might have been a little unclear. I want the characters to know they are the only colored things in a black and white universe. But like you said, colorblind or not.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**You can, [as being invisible](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qlj) imposes no penalties per Paizo's FAQ.**

> Invisibility: Can you see yourself when you're invisible?
>
> The spell doesn't say one way or the other.
>
> Because being invisible doesn't give you penalties on actions that require you to be able to see exactly what you're doing (such as picking a lock), you can assume that you can at least see yourself well enough to perform such actions without penalty. Whether this means you can see yourself as if you were not invisible, can see yourself as a ghostly image, or some other description is up to the GM, so long as the description doesn't hinder your own actions.

It's up to you what exactly they can see, so you can determine if their ghostly image is coloured in.